# How to get all page numbers and their urls?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-crawler

I'm trying to get all pages from category page:
category page is here [link](https://reseller.c-data.co.il/%D7%9E%D7%97%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%91-%D7%9E%D7%97%D7%A9%D7%91%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%99%D7%93%D7%99%D7%9D-DELL-EMC)

At the bottom there is the next page numbers.
I'm try to get all the urls for the next pages :

```
Mydriver = getOrCreateWebdriver()
Main_category = Mydriver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@href]")
for mc in Main_category:
mCat_link = mc.get_attribute("href")
mCat_link = unquote(mCat_link)
mCat_link = mCat_link.replace('#', '')
if (mCat_link in category_list or "changelanguage" in mCat_link):
    continue
else:
    if("reseller.c-data.co.il" in mCat_link):
        category_list.append(mCat_link)
        print(mCat_link)
        if(mc.find_elements_by_class_name("current-page")):
            i=2
            another_page = mCat_link+"#/pageSize=21&viewMode=grid&orderBy=0&pageNumber="+i
            print(another_page)
            i+=1
            another_page = mCat_link + "#/pageSize=21&viewMode=grid&orderBy=0&pageNumber="+i
    else:
        continue
```

I can't find the class and I can't reach to those pages. How can I get them or at least know how many pages there is in the menu?

Comment: Try `mc.find_elements_by_class_name("li.individual-page > a")`

Comment: i've change it to     if(mc.find_elements_by_class_name("li.individual-page > a")):
 - and i've put breakpoint - it's never reached to that point..

Comment: @JustinEzequiel , any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

Apologies, I did not change the method name. It should be `find_elements_by_css_selector`

```
matches = Mydriver.find_elements_by_css_selector("li.individual-page > a")
for e in matches:
    print(e.get_attribute('data-pagenumber'), e.text)
```